# how to assert on output of for loop in selenium java?

Tags: for-loop, selenium-webdriver, assertion

```
public void searchSuccessText()
{
    String searchBarText = Hooks.driver.findElement(By.id("small-searchterms")).getText();
    List<WebElement> result_text = Hooks.driver.findElements(By.className("product-title"));
    int numOfElements = result_text.size();
    for (int j=0; j < numOfElements; j++)
    {
        String resultText = result_text.get(j).getText().toLowerCase();
    
        softAssert.assertEquals(resultText,searchBarText);
        softAssert.assertAll();
    }
}
```

It is expected that the output is to verify that each search result appeared, as it contains what is written in the search barو I do not know how to do it because it is not able to verify the output of the For Loop

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are using TestNG for assertions. Since TestNG doesn't provide any specific assertion to test the contains string. You can use `assertTrue` instead of `assertEquals` like in below example:-

```java
public void searchSuccessText()
{
    String searchBarText = Hooks.driver.findElement(By.id("small-searchterms")).getText();
    List<WebElement> result_text = Hooks.driver.findElements(By.className("product-title"));
    int numOfElements = result_text.size();
    for (int j=0; j < numOfElements; j++)
    {
        String resultText = result_text.get(j).getText().toLowerCase();
    
        softAssert.assertTrue(resultText.contains(searchBarText));
        softAssert.assertAll();
    }
}
```

You can check more example of `assertTrue` [here](https://codingnconcepts.com/java/unit-test-with-junit5-assertions/#asserttrue--assertfalse)